# Space after an alignment

Tags: spacing, align

```
\usepackage{bm} % bold
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % no indent

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} %to have subfigures available

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex [intoc]

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark} % a written or spoken comment.

\newcommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lxor}{\oplus}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lequiv}{\leftrightarrow}
\DeclareMathOperator{\powerset}{\mathcal P}
\DeclareMathOperator{\seg}{seg} % initial segment
\DeclareMathOperator*{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\domain}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\range}{ran}
\DeclareMathOperator{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}

\begin{definition}
\begin{align}
\tag{Equinumerous}
A\approx B \defeq & \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is bijection}\\
\tag{Dominate}
A\leq B 
\defeq & \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is injection}\\
\defeq & \exists g\colon B\to A \text{ is surjection} \notag
\end{align}
\end{definition}
```

I got a very small space after the defeq symbol,
The solution I can find is that move the alignment symbol to the LHS of the defeq symbol.
However, this is just a walk around, sometimes I do need an RHS alignment symbol.
Are there any better solutions?

```
\begin{definition}
\begin{align}
\tag{Equinumerous}
A\approx B &\defeq \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is bijection}\\
\tag{Dominate}
A\leq B 
&\defeq \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is injection}\\
&\defeq \exists g\colon B\to A \text{ is surjection} \notag
\end{align}
\end{definition}
```

Comment: Please make this into a single complete example that others can easily copy and test. For example there is no document class and no `\begin/end{document}`. Additionally it might be an idea to add an image of what it looks like from your side.

Comment: Unrelated: with a few exceptions the `hyperref` package should be loaded last as it has to change other packages

Comment: `\defeq` is not a math operator, so it is wrong to use it like this. It should be a relation. so define it via `\newcommand`  instead. I would also use `\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle\text{def}}{=}` to make the `def` even smaller as it is wider than `=` might even want to use `\mathclap` from `mathtools` on it so it does not disturb spacing at all.

Comment: BTW: the missing space is because you align on the right, then the relation only sees `&` and never adds spacings. If you're aligning on the right remember to use `relation {} & ...`, then the spacing is correct again.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `\DeclareMathOperator` for `\defeq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tag{Equinumerous}
A\approx B \defeq{} & \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is bijection}\\
\tag{Dominate}
A\leq B
\defeq{} & \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is injection}\\
\defeq{} & \exists g\colon B\to A \text{ is surjection}
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
\tag{Equinumerous}
A\approx B &\defeq \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is bijection}\\
\tag{Dominate}
A\leq B
&\defeq \exists f\colon A\to B \text{ is injection}\\
&\defeq \exists g\colon B\to A \text{ is surjection}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Now `\defeq` is treated as a binary relation symbol, as it should. I see no problem in using the second method. In the first case you need `{}` after `\defeq` or there would be no space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever to place the alignment marker `&` to the right of a relation, remember to use

```
relation {} & ....
```

without the `{}` the relation only sees `&` and it will not employ any spacing after the relation.